# Как правильно заполнить RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, recyclerview, retrofit

Нужно заполнить адаптер RecyclerView, как правильно это сделать?

Модель класса

```
public class Data {
@SerializedName("dialogs")
@Expose
private List<Dialog> dialogs = null;
@SerializedName("end")
@Expose
private Boolean end;
@SerializedName("pages_count")
@Expose
private Integer pagesCount;

public List<Dialog> getDialogs() {
    return dialogs;
}

public void setDialogs(List<Dialog> dialogs) {
    this.dialogs = dialogs;
}

public Boolean getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public void setEnd(Boolean end) {
    this.end = end;
}

public Integer getPagesCount() {
    return pagesCount;
}

public void setPagesCount(Integer pagesCount) {
    this.pagesCount = pagesCount;
}}
```

Интерфейс

```
public interface TestService {
@GET("api")
Call<DataResponseJSON> getData();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://service.site/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build(); }
```

И собственно сам адаптер

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Data> data;

public DataAdapter(ArrayList<Data> dataList) {
    this.data = dataList;
}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.accauntName.setText(data.get(i).getDialogs().get(i).getFromUser().getName());
    viewHolder.accountAge.setText(data.get(i).getDialogs().get(i).getFromUser().getBirthday().getAge());
    viewHolder.message.setText(data.get(i).getDialogs().get(i).getLastMessage().getMessage());
    viewHolder.time.setText(data.get(i).getDialogs().get(i).getLastMessage().getLastUpdate());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView accauntName,accountAge,message,time;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        accauntName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.accauntNameTextView);
        accountAge = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.accountAgeTextView);
        message = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);

    }
}}
```

Как мне теперь в activity загрузить данные в RecyclerView?

Класс DataResponseJSON

```
public class DataResponseJSON {
private Data[] dataJSON;

public Data[] getDataJSON() {
    return dataJSON;
}
```

}

В activity делаю так

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<Data> data;
private DataAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initViews();
    loadJSON();
}

private void initViews(){
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
private void loadJSON(){
    TestService request = TestService.retrofit.create(TestService.class);
    Call<DataResponseJSON> call = request.getData();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<DataResponseJSON>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DataResponseJSON> call, Response<DataResponseJSON> response) {

            DataResponseJSON jsonResponse = response.body();
            Log.i("Data", String.valueOf(response.code())); //Код возвращает 200
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getDataJSON())); // Здесь происходит ошибка ((
            adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DataResponseJSON> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Лог ошибки

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: example.com.test, PID: 2673
java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
    at linkyou.ru.test.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант у Вас есть данные перед инициализацией адаптера и делаете

```
public DataAdapter(ArrayList<Data> dataList) {//этот список это и есть ваши данные
this.data = dataList; 
}
```

Второй вариант инициализировать адаптер с пустым списком, получить данные и обновить адаптер:

```
DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(new ArrayList<Data>()) // инициализация с пустым списком
```

в адаптере добавляете свой метод

```
public void updateData(List<Data> items) {
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(items)
    notifyDataSetChanged();//метод перезагружает весь список
}
```

После чего получили данные и сетите новые, из активити дергаете метод

```
adapter.updateData(dataList);
```

UPDATE:

```
private void loadJSON(){
TestService request = TestService.retrofit.create(TestService.class);
Call<DataResponseJSON> call = request.getData();
call.enqueue(new Callback<DataResponseJSON>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<DataResponseJSON> call, Response<DataResponseJSON> response) {
        //тут добавьте проверку
       if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null && response.body().getDataJSON() != null){
        DataResponseJSON jsonResponse = response.body();
        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getDataJSON())); // Здесь происходит ошибка ((
        adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<DataResponseJSON> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
    }
  });
}
```

UPDATE_2:

```
public class DataResponseJSON {
 @SerializedName("data")
 private Data[] dataJSON;

 public Data[] getDataJSON() {
  return dataJSON;
 }
}
```

Comment: Делал по первому варианту, выдает ошибку. Если не сложно дайте рабочий пример пожалуйста

Comment: Можно точнее, какую ошибку?

Comment: Выше я все описал, при заполнении массива `data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getDataJSON())); `      'FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: examlpe.com.test, PID: 2673
java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
at linkyou.ru.test.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:55)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)`

Comment: ошибка в респонсе у вас там null приходит вот и падает. jsonResponse.getDataJSON() - null

Comment: обновил ответ, добавьте проверку в респонсе, но это не решает проблему что возвращается null тут надо смотреть что на Api и что за модель

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но дело в том что данные принимается нормально и я могу получить все данные, проблема именно в выводе в RecyclerView!

Comment: Не знаю как принимаются данные но ошибка явно говорит  java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null  Вы в. java.util.Arrays.asList пытаетесь засунуть null! это не проблема списка или адаптера. Возможно проблема в неправильно преобразовании данных (парсинге)

Comment: добавьте мою проверку и продебажте, заходит ли программа в этот if

Comment: У Вас в моделе DataResponseJSON нет @SerializedName - скорей всего проблема в этом

Comment: Я руководствовался примером из https://www.learn2crack.com/tag/recycler-view, если вы знаете как можно обойтись без класса DataResponseJSON, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: скиньте весь респонс что вам приходит

Comment: Как вам весь респонс отправлю, он же как мне известно в виде массива формируется!

Comment: респонс это строка в формате JSON (обычно) которая парсится и преобразуется в модель. Для проверки моей теории засетьте адаптер таким образом  data = new ArrayList<>(); - если не упадет значит проблема в том что вернулся null, а не в адаптере.

Comment: на какой сервер вы стучитесь?

Comment: http://part4.ru/test.json

Comment: проверил `data = new ArrayList<>();` ошибок не было

Comment: обновил ответ, добавьте @SerializedName("data") в модель DataResponseJSON